# Is it possible to update the addressbar without a server round-trip?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I have a treeview inplemented in CSS, when a user clicks a folder on the treeview I'd like to update the URL in the address bar without causing a server round-trip.

The HTML looks a little like this:-

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="www.example.com/blah?id=12345">Folder</a>
        <ol>
            <li>Child</li>
        </ol
    </li>
<ol>
```

The CSS I have handles the expanding of the folder but I'd like the Address bar URL to update so I can deep link to a particular folder but there is no need from a code perspective to do a round-trip to the server
Is there any way of achiveing this? I have a feeling this might be impossible because of potention phishing??

I'm using HTML5, CSS2/3, jquery and ASP.NET MVC3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with HTML 5 History API it is possible, as is done on [gawker](http://www.gawker.com) sites and on [github](http://www.github.com). But the condition is that both the pages be from same server. Like you can change the address from:

```
http://www.exemple.com/page1.html
```

to:

```
http://www.exemple.com/page2.html
```

using `history.replaceState` function. It is not widely supported in all browsers ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=history)). Your best bet prehaps is to use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js)

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 adds a History API, which allows you to use [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) in modern browsers to update the URL. You are restricted to the same domain for security reasons.

This won't be supported in IE until IE10. Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome have all implemented it.

Comment: So *that's* how those new pages are annoying the heck out of me :(

Comment: ha thanks mozilla - Service Unavailable 
The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. I'm stuck with IE9 (internal site) for now so I'm going to use history.js